# Optimizing a program by vectorized notation

Tags: performance, matlab, optimization, performance-testing

Hi all I am working on Image processing and have written a short piece of code in **MATLAB**. The code is quite slow.

I am giving my code snippet here

```
for i=1:10
    //find c1,c2,c3
    //c1 c2 and c3 change at each iteration

    u = (1./((abs(P-c1))^m) + 1./((abs(P-c2))^m) + 1./((abs(P-c3))^m));
    u1 = 1./((abs(P-c1))^m)./u;
    u2 = 1./((abs(P-c2))^m)./u;    
    u3 = 1./((abs(P-c3))^m)./u;
end
```

Let me explain the variables here:

```
P,u,u1,u2 and u3 are all matrices of size 512x512
c1,c2 and c3 are constants of dimension 1x1
m is a constant with value = 2
```

I want to **repeat** this operations in a loop (say 10 times). However my code is quite slow.

The results of the profiler are given below :

The total running time of the program was 4.6 secs. However the four steps listed above itself takes abour 80% of the time.

[image]

So I wanted to make my code run **faster**.
**MY FIRST EDIT**

My changed code snippet

```
for i=1:10

    //find c1 and c2
    //c1 and c2 changes at each iteration

    a=((abs(P-c1))^m); 
    b=((abs(P-c2))^m); 
    c=((abs(P-c3))^m);

    x=1./a; y=1./b; z=1./c;
    u = (x + y + z);
    u1 = x./u;
    u2 = y./u;    
    u3 = z./u;
end
```

Now the program computes in 2.47 seconds computation time for the above steps are given below:

[image]

So this is way much more faster than my first method.

**2nd edit**
    for i=1:10
        //find c1,c2,c3
        //c1 c2 and c3 change at each iteration

```
    a=(P-c1).*(P-c1); 
    b=(P-c2).*(P-c2); 
    c=(P-c3).*(P-c3);

    x=1./a; y=1./b; z=1./c;
    u = (x + y + z);
    u1 = x./u;
    u2 = y./u;    
    u3 = z./u;
end
```

Now the program computes in 0.808 seconds.

The four steps described above computes above very quickly.

[image]

I am sure it can be made even faster. Can you guys please help me to further **optimize** *my code*.
It would be extremely helpful for matrices larger size than 512 such as 1024 , 2048 or likewise.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why image-processing tag? the performance tag makes more sense.

Comment: @am working on image processing. The code snippet is from a clustering algorithm

Comment: adding a performance tag

Comment: right, but if in the post, there is no image-processing related problems. it is better not to mention that. This helps to involve more people in the field.

Comment: thanks for the suggestions . I am removing the said tag

Comment: @roni You said you are running the four lines 10 times in a loop. So what is changing in those 10 for-loops. Are all the matrices, namely, `P,u,u1,u2 and u3` changing? My second question is, do you have these 10 matrices available to you beforehand? It would be better if you could post your entire for-loop.

Comment: @Parag The value of the P matrix remains the same for all the iterations. The other matrices u,u1,u2,u3 and the constants c1 and c2 changes for each iteration. I have re-added the relevant parts. Please look through my code again.

Comment: @roni I can't comment much with this much information. The reason is as follows: 1. If the process of finding `c1, c2, c3` is not vectorizable, then not much can be done as of now. 2.  If it can be vectorized then actually we can use `c1,c2,c3` as a `10x1` array and calculate `u,u1,u2,u3` simultaneously for all the 10 values. 3. Last suggestion I can give you is, try converting this into a `parfor` loop and see if it makes any difference.

Comment: @Parag Thanks for all your suggestions. I am re-editing and expanding my code to make it more explicit. I am adding also the parts about how I am generating the c1,c2,c3 constants. Lastly thanks for the third suggestion. I did not know about parfor loop. I will look into it.

Comment: Your optimization isn't equivalent to your original code.  A^m is the matrix power.  A^2 is A*A, as in matrix multiplication.  However, your new code writes A.*A, which is element-by-element multiplication, which is much faster.  So which do you want?  Each element squared (A.^2 or A.*A), or the matrix squared (A^2 or A*A)?

Comment: @Peter I get your suggestion now. Yes you are right. I want the elements of the matrix squared. So my first code is wrong and the optimized one is correct. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

The first suggestion is:

if **m = 2** and it is not changing, why you don't try these alternatives:

```
A*A
```

and if **m = 2** then do you really need **abs** ?

this part that you are doing

```
1./a
```

is faster than

```
a.^(-1)
```

so I don't see any better option in this part.

Another thing you can try is this. instead of:

```
x=1./a; y=1./b; z=1./c;
    u = (x + y + z);
    u1 = x./u;
    u2 = y./u;    
    u3 = z./u;
```

You can have this:

```
    u = (x + y + z);
    u1 = 1./(a.*u);
    u2 = 1./(b.*u);    
    u3 = 1./(c.*u);
```

this way I guess it is a little bit faster by removing 3 variables. but the code becomes less readable.

Comment: used your helpful suggestions! Please see the result. Any further modifications you would like to suggest?

Comment: sorry but could you recheck your edited parts. I believe it is wrong. For example: u1 = x./u = 1./u./x and not 1./(a.*u)

Comment: for example x=1./a and u1=x./u; then we can replace x in the second formula with 1./a. the result is u1=1./(a./u); So, 1./(a.*u) is correct (checked in MATLAB as well) why are you getting error?

Answer (score 1):

Your current code is:

```
a=((abs(P-c1))^m); 
b=((abs(P-c2))^m); 
c=((abs(P-c3))^m);

x=1./a; y=1./b; z=1./c;
u = (x + y + z);
u1 = x./u;
u2 = y./u;    
u3 = z./u;
```

Firstly, realize that the absolute value function is multiplicative. So `|AB| = |A|x|B|`. Now, `abs(P-C1)^m` is equivalent to `abs( (P-C1)^m )`.

Just a preliminary glance at it suggests that some of the computation in the bottleneck can be reused. Specifically, since `c1`,`c2` and `c3` are constants, the computation can be sped up a little bit if you try to reuse them (at the expense of additional memory).

```
temp_P2 = P*P;
temp_PCA = P*ones(size(P));
temp_PCB = ones(size(P))*P;

a = abs(temp_P2 - c1*temp_PCA - c1*temp_PCB + c1^2 * length(P))
```

The computation of `temp_PCA` and `temp_PCB` can also be avoided since multiplication by a constant matrix always amounts to the construction of a rank 1 matrix with either constant rows or columns.

I don't claim that any of these modifications will speed up your code but they are definitely worth trying.

Comment: could you please explain your steps more. I could not understand the way you compute a matrix. Did you just expand the equation?

Comment: Hi again. I tried your suggestions. Unfortunately it increases the computation time. It seems like (P-c1).*(P-c1) is computationally faster than your edited seems. Anyway thanks for your help. I will be extremely glad to hear further.

Comment: @roni. Yes, I just expanded the matrix equation. Also, be careful, if `m=2`, you still need the `abs` sign. (NKN and I thought that it is redundant but I was able to find a counterexample).

Comment: why is abs needed if m=2 ? could you please elaborate. Please provide the counterexample .

Comment: @roni `abs` in MATLAB takes the absolute value of each element. If you have a matrix `A`, `A^2` doesn't necessarily make each element positive. Consider `A = [1 -2; -2 1]`. `A*A = [5 -4; -4 5]`. However, `abs(A*A) = [5 4 ; 4 5]`.

Comment: @roni You're confusing element-wise squaring with matrix squaring.

Comment: Thanks @Peter and Nitish for your clarification